# Sprite Animation in Three.js getting pixelated

Tags: javascript, css, three.js, css-sprites

I'm trying out the texture animation with a sprite sheet having more than 30 frames. However, even though I'm able to flawlessly execute the required animation the output is getting pixelated if the frames cross more than 30. Kindly let me know why this happens.

Referred example below: 
http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Texture-Animation.html

```
function TextureAnimator(texture, tilesHoriz, tilesVert, numTiles, tileDispDuration) 
{   
    // note: texture passed by reference, will be updated by the update function.

    this.tilesHorizontal = tilesHoriz;
    this.tilesVertical = tilesVert;

    // how many images does this spritesheet contain?
    //  usually equals tilesHoriz * tilesVert, but not necessarily,
    //  if there at blank tiles at the bottom of the spritesheet. 
    this.numberOfTiles = numTiles;
    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
    texture.repeat.set( 1 / this.tilesHorizontal, 1 / this.tilesVertical );

    // how long should each image be displayed?
    this.tileDisplayDuration = tileDispDuration;

    // how long has the current image been displayed?
    this.currentDisplayTime = 0;

    // which image is currently being displayed?
    this.currentTile = 0;

    this.update = function( milliSec )
    {
        this.currentDisplayTime += milliSec;
        while (this.currentDisplayTime > this.tileDisplayDuration)
        {
            this.currentDisplayTime -= this.tileDisplayDuration;
            this.currentTile++;
            if (this.currentTile == this.numberOfTiles)
                this.currentTile = 0;
            var currentColumn = this.currentTile % this.tilesHorizontal;
            texture.offset.x = currentColumn / this.tilesHorizontal;
            var currentRow = Math.floor( this.currentTile / this.tilesHorizontal );
            texture.offset.y = currentRow / this.tilesVertical;
        }
    };
}
```

Texture with more than 25 frames are getting pixelated

```
var runnerTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/run.png' );
// a texture with 10 frames arranged horizontally, display each for 75 millisec
annie = new TextureAnimator( runnerTexture, 10, 1, 10, 75 ); 
var runnerMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: runnerTexture } );
```

Comment: What size image are you using to hold the frames? More frames will need a larger image to maintain pixel detail per frame.

Comment: @Radio  image size which i'm using is 57300*1389 pixels and it has 32 frames.

Comment: I would take a look at [this link about maximum texture size](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/870). I imagine the image is being resized to fit within webGL limits. I would then look at https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/Texture and use a .mp4 video file instead of animated frames.